# Как сверстать макет, что бы картинка всегда занимала 70 процентов экрана и растягивалась максимально по ширине?

Tags: android

Ребят, я что-то запутался в верстке макета своего.У меня с firebase выводиться картинка пользователя в ImageView (она должна быть на 70 процентов экрана) под ней должно выводиться Логин пользователя в TextView и рядом в этой же строке его возраст тоже в TextView. и под этим всем должен выводиться RatingBar.
Получается выглядеть должно примерно так [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я написал код разметки, но что то у меня не отображает как надо, картинка во первых может не занимать всю ширину, тут зависит какая картинка попадеться. А мне надо что бы она растягивалась на всю ширину экрана. Я разные варианты верстки пробовал, но что то такой макет вроде и легкий не получается сделать.Вот мой последний код, подскажите кто знает как такое сверстать то

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:clickable="true"
>
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layoutImageUser"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center"

    >
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/userImageLine"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/profile"
        android:layout_weight="60"
        />
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="30"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@color/layoutUserColor"
        >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/loginUser"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Имя"
            android:textSize="40dp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ageUser"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="20"
            android:textSize="40dp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"
            />


    </FrameLayout>
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="10"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@color/layoutUserColor"
        >
        <RatingBar
            android:id="@+id/ratingBarUser"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:stepSize="0.25"
            android:numStars="5"
            android:rating="4.5"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"/>
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

В `ImageView` надо добавить `android:scaleType="centerCrop"` чтобы картинка "растягивалась" на весь контейнер. И картинка в верстке занимает 60%, а не 70%.

Comment: спасибо вам большое))